# Exception: null. The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory

Tags: linux, flutter, android-studio, ubuntu

I try to using Flutter in Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. with Android Studio 4.1.2.
When I try to run flutter app to a real device, I'm getting this error:

> Exception: null. The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
> Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.

The permissions output of the Flutter SDK:

```
-rw-rw-rw-  1 yacine yacine 10620 Feb 26 14:51 analysis_options.yaml
-rw-rw-rw-  1 yacine yacine  2879 Feb 26 14:51 AUTHORS
-drwxrwxrwx  4 yacine yacine  4096 Feb 26 14:51 bin
-rw-rw-rw-  1 yacine yacine  2723 Jan 25 20:42 CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
-rw-rw-rw-  1 yacine yacine   711 Jan 25 20:42 CODEOWNERS
-rw-rw-rw-  1 yacine yacine  5184 Feb 26 14:51 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-rw-rw-  1 yacine yacine  1591 Feb 26 14:51 dartdoc_options.yaml
-drwxrwxrwx 15 yacine yacine  4096 Feb 26 14:51 dev
-drwxrwxrwx 13 yacine yacine  4096 Jan 25 20:45 examples
-rw-rw-rw-  1 yacine yacine  1731 Jan 25 20:42 flutter_console.bat
-rw-rw-rw-  1 yacine yacine   296 Jan 25 20:45 flutter_root.iml
-rw-rw-rw-  1 yacine yacine  1519 Jan 25 20:42 LICENSE
-drwxrwxrwx 13 yacine yacine  4096 Feb 26 14:51 packages
-rw-rw-rw-  1 yacine yacine  1107 Jan 25 20:42 PATENT_GRANT
-rw-rw-rw-  1 yacine yacine  4643 Feb 26 14:51 README.md
-rw-rw-rw-  1 yacine yacine  3342 Feb 26 14:51 SECURITY.md
-rw-rw-rw-  1 yacine yacine    14 Feb 26 15:55 version
```

Comment: Did you checked if in preferences > Languages & frameworks > dart  If the path to dart sdk is correct?

Comment: Yes, I checked the path to dart SDK is correct

Comment: Try this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73674#issuecomment-758011657

Comment: I have tried it, but always the same problem.

Comment: The problem is with your permissions.. try to cut the sdk into the project folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** Change the permission of the flutter SDK folder + the permission of the project.

**Long answer:** After I try many things I found the solution for my problem:  All what I try to do from the first time is to change the permission of my flutter SDK folder. But what I did not expect is to change the permission of my project ( Because I was using it without the appearance of this problem ). What I did to resolve the problem is to change the directory of my project from:

> /media/yacine/File/Projects/Android/flutter_app

with this permission

```
drwxrwxr-x 1 yacine users 4096 Feb 26 18:37 flutter_app
```

to:

> /home/yacine/flutter_app

with this permission

```
drwxrwxr-x 13 yacine yacine 4096 Feb 27 01:12 flutter_app
```